# Rank by a column and a measure

Tags: powerbi, dax, rank

I have a [table](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=8ecc89077e4119a6d4607c4d29c12882).

There is a measure that calculates the defiance rate as:

```
M = 1 - ( DIVIDE (SUM (Finalised), SUM(Goal)))
```

I need to rank the branch's defiance rate in the region where they are located.

For example:

In the "South" region, branches should be ranked as:

1. Number3 (with most defiance)
2. Number1
3. Number2 (with least defiance)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution without adding new table by adding new column for calculation, the only weakness is that the order is not in sequential, you can try create a new table with unique ID, there it can solved, accept if help :)

[image]

```
Ranking = RANKX(Sheet1,
            1-DIVIDE(
            CALCULATE(SUM(Sheet1[finalised]),
                FILTER(ALL(Sheet1),Sheet1[branch]=EARLIER(Sheet1[branch]))),
                    CALCULATE(SUM(Sheet1[goal]),
                        FILTER(ALL(Sheet1),Sheet1[branch]=EARLIER(Sheet1[branch])))))
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for aid. the problem here is, ranking should be by branch name, not reconciliation name. all goals and finalized numbers need to sum by branch and rated. For example, branch named "number1" has a total of 100 (goal), and 79 finalized reconciliations. The deficiance rate of branch number1 is : 1-(79/100) = 21%. As similar, deficiance rate should be calculated in all South region and ranked.

Comment: By removing the rankx, you want obtain exactly the amount as you mentioned, probably you can show how it should be like in a image, I think my formula has achieved your outcome?